# Return vertexes of separate subgraph

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph

I have this graph:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c('a','b','c'),y=c('d','c','f'))
g<-graph.data.frame(df,directed=F)
```

is there a way to return two lists of vertexes according to which subgraph they belong?

I'd like to get to this output:

```
 vertex id
1      a  1
2      d  1
3      b  2
4      c  2
5      f  2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See `clusters`. Btw. what you are looking for is the components of the graph. (The igraph terminology is confusing, too.)

```
data.frame(vertex=V(g)$name, id=clusters(g)$membership)
#   vertex id
# 1      a  1
# 2      b  2
# 3      c  2
# 4      d  1
# 5      f  2
```

Comment: Thank you.It's work. 
However, I try in this way:
m<-multilevel.community (g)
data.frame(vertex=m$names,id=m$membership)